# How do I make a page no fall asleep when it is no focused on?

Tags: javascript, html, focus

I'm making a clicker/tycoon web game but when the page is not focused on, the page will not be active, is there any way to make it so the page doesn't becomes inactive if not focused on, or is there any ways around it?

Comment: `setInterval` will always run in the background. If you are using `requestAnimationFrame`, this will stop when there is no focus.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I'm using a script like this to handle all of the money and time but the tab is immediately put to sleep once it is not focused on, is the `window` part messing it up?

`window.setInterval(function() {
//code
}, 10);`

Comment: I have read that the browser reduces the interval to `1000ms` once the browser loses focus. So, one thing to do would be to get the time the browser loses focus, and then get the time it gains focus, and then do some math to check how many seconds have passed. Then you would update their balance based on the math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser's `setInterval` doesn't run at max speed when there is no focus, so to counter that you need to get the window blur/focus events and do the math yourself. Here is an example of how this is done. Click on the window to create focus, then unfocus on the window for a short time, then give the window focus again (repeat).

**Note:** Don't forget to stop giving cash in the original loop otherwise you will be calculating more than once and giving extra cash.

```js
// The current balance
let balance = 0
// The time the window lost focus
let focusLostTime = null
// The amount of cash per second
let cashPerSec = 2
// Wheter we should calc balance in the main loop
let calcBalance = true
// The output 
let balanceOutput = document.getElementById('balance')

window.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  // Set the time the window lost focus
  focusLostTime = Date.now()
  calcBalance = false
})

window.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  // If this hasn't been set don't do anything
  if(!focusLostTime) return
  calcBalance = true
  // Calculate the elapsed time 
  // This will be in seconds and posibly have a decimal
  let elapsedTime = (Date.now() - focusLostTime) / 1000
  // Multiply the elapsed time by the amount of cash they get per second
  balance += elapsedTime * cashPerSec
  
})

////////////////////////////////////////
// This is just for example update loop
////////////////////////////////////////

// When the last tick was
let lastTick = Date.now()

setInterval(() => {
  if (!calcBalance) return
  let elapsedTime = (Date.now() - lastTick) / 1000
  balance += cashPerSec * elapsedTime
  lastTick = Date.now()
  balanceOutput.innerText = balance
}, 10)
```

```html
Balance: <span id="balance"></span>
```